# Error Adding new row

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I am trying to insert a row in excel sheet, I am not able to add a new row in a particular sheet say Sheet 1. where as I am able to insert a row in sheet 2 or sheet 3 of the same excel sheet.

I am getting this following error

> Excel cannot complete this task with available resource. Choose less data or close application.

Comment: This error generally occurs when you work with big amount of data and either your system is very busy (not enough free RAM) either the desired activity requires too much resources. How big is your sheet? How much formulas does it contain? Disabling calculations during insert of sheet might help.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I don't know (without actually seeing the Excel workbook) how there can be any other answer ... I suggest you move your comment to an answer (but focus on what resouce could mean - RAM/CPU etc, and how they can test it by (as you said) removing calculations etc.

Comment: Just curious what if you copy the entire contents from sheet1 to say a blank sheet5 and try the same operation of inserting row now in sheet5 (within the same workbook). Do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when you work with big amount of data and either your system is very busy (not enough free RAM) either the desired activity requires too much resources.

At first have a look on your task manager and close some programs if necessary.

If that doesn't help than probably the problem is the size or complexity of your sheet. Try to delete unused range of you sheet (that may contain formatting information increasing the size of your sheet) and / or disable calculations during during the addition of the row.

You can find further tips at [Microsoft support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2779852).